# Связь между таблицами

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Столкнулся с одной задачей.
У меня есть таблица **User**. В ней есть поля

- name
- email
- **skill_dance**
- **skill_sing**
- **skill_model**

Так же есть таблица **Skills**. В ней есть поля

- id
- level_skill

Это поле может содержать только 3 значения.

1. Есть опыт
2. Нет опыта
3. Профессионал

Поля из таблицы **User** (skill_dance,skill_sing,skill_model) будут содержать значение из таблицы **Skills**.
На данный момент, я не знаю, как организовать свзять, между этими таблицами, чтобы они как бы унаследовали эти значения с таблицы **Skills**. 
Я конечно могу создать 3 разных сущности, *DanceSkill*, *SingSkill*, *ModelSkill*, но не вижу в этом смысла и считаю лишней водой. Не хочу плодить слишком много сущностей.
Помогите организовать связь между таблицами, чтобы избежать создания лишних сущностей.

Comment: Не совсем понял суть проблемы. Почему не сделать FK на таблицу `Skills`?

Comment: А что мешает просто хранить в skill_dance,skill_sing,skill_model идентификаторы из Skills? Хотя, я бы вообще не стала так уж слишком нормализовать таблицу и хранила бы конечные данные прямо в исходной. Т.е. таблица Skills вообще лишняя...

Comment: Насчет хранения в таком виде, как вы говорите Еlla Svetlaya не совсем правильно. Это нарушает, закон о нормальной форме, не помню какой именно.

Comment: Soon, покажи пожалуйста примером, что ты имеешь в виду, как это реализовать именно в связях

Comment: @ДаниэльСайфулин в теории может и нарушает (3ю нормальную форму), но на практике Вы получите от такой связи только геморрой. Такую нормализацию хорошо делать только если таблица `Skills` постоянно меняется или содержит множество строк...

Comment: До поры до времени будет польза. Но когда встанет задача с выборкой пользователей с определенными скилами, вот тут придет как раз тот геморрой :)

Comment: @ДаниэльСайфулин геморрой с выборкой будет как раз, если Вы реализуете свою задумку со связями... замучаетесь с `join`'ами. Но если очень хочется, то я уже написала, как сделать связи. В исходной таблице храните идентификаторы.

Comment: не вижу проблем с выборкой именно с join'ми. В рельсах это не так сложно делается. Но все равно тебе спасибо за предложенный ответ.

Comment: Я с рельсами не работал, но, полагаю, Вам стоит ознакомиться с [Active Records Associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html)

Answer (score 1):

я думаю стоит хранить в полях skill_dance, skill_sing и т д просто id сущности skill_level. Тоесть ты получишь связь с сущностью skill, по которой можно выяснить требуемый уровень. позволит избежать создания множества одинаковых сущностей.
Также можно сделать просто в полях skill_dance и т д, хранить integer а в Model.rb описать enum для необходимого поля